# Is it possible through SQL injection to launch an UPDATE/DELETE statement from an INSERT/SELECT statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Let's take the following vulnerable query ($id not being escaped):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id
```

Would it be possible in MySQL 5.x to modify some data through an **UPDATE** statement which would appear **inside** the hacked SELECT statement?

I thought about something using benchmark() function:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = id OR benchmark(1, (UPDATE ...))
```

But it doesn't seem to work:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE ...

Any other possibilities not using stored procedure?

**Edit: and nor using *multiple queries* of course...**

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention it is not using a multiple queries capable driver.

Comment: Voting to close as a pointless question.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the driver this may pass:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = id; UPDATE table ...
```

Comment: Notably, PHP's MySQL API does *not* permit multiple statements of that form (but subqueries and unions, for selecting other data, work).

Answer (score 1):

[Multiple queries.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html)